# Generate a highchart based on the output of an array

Tags: php, mysql, charts, highcharts

**UPDATE** I have updated my code in response to @MichaelRushton comments. I am now using Highcharts but I am having trouble getting output to the data series.

I now have the following array generated from a mysql query, and I would like to output it into a line chart. My Y-Axis should contain the amount, x-axis is the date range, and legend is the different items plotted on the chart.

```
   // Call the stored procedure
   $stmt->execute();                    

   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $array[$row['legend']][$row['date']] = $row['amount'];
       //print_r($array);
   }


   chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

   chart: {
     renderTo: 'container',
     type: 'line'
   },

   xAxis:
   {
    categories: [2012-03-01, 2012-03-02, 2012-03-03, 2012-03-04, 2012-03-05, 2012-03-06, 2012-03-07, 2012-03-08, 2012-03-09, 2012-03-10, 2012-03-11, 2012-03-12, 2012-03-13, 2012-03-14, 2012-03-15, 2012-03-16, 2012-03-17, 2012-03-18, 2012-03-19, 2012-03-20, 2012-03-21, 2012-03-22, 2012-03-23, 2012-03-24, 2012-03-25, 2012-03-26, 2012-03-27, 2012-03-28, 2012-03-29, 2012-03-30, 2012-03-31],
   },

   series:
   [

<?php
     foreach ($array as $legend => $data)
         {
           echo '{';
           echo "name: '" . $legend . "',";

           $values = array();

           for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; ++$i)
           {
             $values[] = isset($data[$i]) ? $data[$i] : 0;
           }

           echo 'data: [' . implode(', ', $values) . '],';
           echo '},';

         }
?>
],
 }
 );

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
)
```

This code is presenting me with the following output:

```
series: [ {name: 'Something Tastier',data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],},{name: 'Something Tasty',data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],}, ], } );
```

The seems right except there is no values outputting to the data series. If anyone has any further ideas it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts is my favourite option for graphs. It might be worth structuring your array to look like:

```
Array (

  [legend_one] => Array
  (

    [2012-03-01] => 100
    [2012-03-02] => 200
    [2012-03-03] => 300
    ...

  )

  [legend_two] => Array
  (

    // Day of the month    
    [2012-03-01] => 100
    [2012-03-02] => 200
    [2012-03-03] => 300
    ...

  )

  ...

)
```

You can then use Highcharts like this:

**Edit:** Now uses full date rather than just day, made the month dynamic (using `$start` variable), and started the day iterator at 0 rather than 1 to remove the need for `$i - 1` when using `strtotime` to work out the next date.

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

  xAxis:
  {

    categories: [

<?php

      // You could dynamically set this date using $_GET/$_POST
      $start = '2012-03-01';

      $dates = array();

      for ($i = 0, $days = date('t', strtotime($start)); $i < $days; ++$i)
      {
        $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start . ' + ' . $i . ' day'));
      }

      echo "'" . implode("', '", $dates) . "'";

?>

    ],

  },

  series:
  [

<?php

    foreach ($array as $legend => $data)
    {

      echo '{';

      echo "name: '" . $legend . "',";

      $values = array();

      for ($i = 0; $i < $days; ++$i)
      {

        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start . ' + ' . $i . ' day'));

        $values[] = isset($data[$date]) ? $data[$date] : 0;

      }

      echo 'data: [' . implode(', ', $values) . '],';

      echo '},';

    }

?>

  ],

}
);
```

Comment: Hi Michael, that looks very useful thanks. I'm currently using PDO $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); to render my array. Any ideas on how I might alter the output to the array you suggested?

Comment: Iterate over the result and do `$array[$row['legend']][$row['day']] = $row['amount'];`

Comment: Thanks Michael code seems to be getting there now. I am having trouble  getting the data series updated.

Comment: Deleted previous comment; I've edited my example code to account for full dates as the key for the amount value. I've also tidied up the code to generate the categories.

Comment: My pleasure. As you might have seen, I've also included the `$start` variable to make it easy for you to use other years/months without having to change the script (other than to change `'2012-03-01'` to some `$_GET`/`$_POST` variable (or other of your own)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your php array output useful fr highcharts using. Try `json_encode`. And take a look here http://code.google.com/p/highchartwrapper/

Answer (score 0):

You are going the wrong way. If you searching for something that is already available, then you should output the data in the way, **they accept**. Not the other way around.

With that being said, try [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/). It has wide support for different formats.